# Physical interpretation of the Maxwell stress tensor

Tags: electromagnetism

In 'Introduction to Electrodynamics' by D. Griffiths, shortly after introducing the Maxwell stress tensor there is a paragraph concerning the physical interpretation of the stress tensor $\boldsymbol{T}$

> Physically, $\boldsymbol{T}$ is the force per unit area (or stress) acting on the surface. More precisely, $T_{ij}$ is the force (per unit area) in the $i$th direction acting on an element of the surface oriented in the $j$th direction - "diagonal" elements ($T_{xx}$, $T_{yy}$, $T_{zz}$) represent pressures, and "off-diagonal" elements ($T_{xy}$,$T_{xz}$, etc.) are shears.

I understand where all this comes from mathematically, but I fail to grasp how this translates into an actual force, and specifically what is meant by "an element of the surface *oriented* in the $j$th direction". Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246795/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-maxwell-stress-tensor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means a surface element whose tangent plane has a normal in the $j$th direction. For a flat surface, we can shorten that to the normal to the surface pointing in the $j$th direction. For a curved surface, each infinitesimal patch has its own tangent plane.

Comment: It is implied that the surface element is slightly charged; otherwise there is no force to apply to ;-)

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski I was replying to the OP's question of what the surface element comment meant. The $i$th component of the force has a clear interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of it is, take a surface with area element $d{\vec A}$.  The force felt on that surface has components given by:

$$F^{i} = \int\sum_{j} T^{ij}dA^{j}$$

The point of the off-diagonal components is that if they are present, this force will be in a different direction than that given by $d{\vec A}$, even for the case of the area element being a flat surface aligned with one of the axes.

Comment: Force can be in a different direction even for diagonal T; it suffices that the diagonal elements are not the same.

Comment: @JánLalinský yes, of course, I'm sorry, I was thinking for the case of a flat area element aligned with one of the axes.  Will edit answer.

Comment: wouldn't we need to say something about the charge / current density at that area element to deduce the force?

Comment: @creillyucla : From the fact that we're doign this in three dimensions, I thought we were talking about the ordinary stress tensor, which is a concept from non-electrodynamic classical mechanics, of which the electromagnetic one is a generalization.

Comment: @creillyucla, charge and current in the whole body, not just its surface will be important for the deduction, but this deduction then leads to the above formula for force on the whole body where its current or charge density do not appear; everything relevant to force is hidden in the components of the EM stress tensor.

Comment: @JánLalinský: doesn't the Lorentz force law read ${\dot p}^{a} = F^{ab}j_{b}$, so the information about the charge lives in the current density?  That's how I've always interpreted it.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer that is true; $j_b$ are distributions that characterize charge and current density of some body in some reference frame. The force expression $\int dV\, F^{ab}j_b$ can be rewritten (under some conditions) as $\int dV\, \partial_b T^{ba}$, using the EM stress-energy tensor $T$ and without using $j^b$.